# 'If' Statement in Do Loop type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched the web trying to figure out why I am getting a type mismatch error on my If statement, but can't seem to get my head wrapped around it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.  By the way, the `i` integer is declared in a previous section of code.

```
Do While i < 25000
j = 4
Range("AV4:AV550").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AU4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Check for a new high value
    Do Until j = 551
        If Range("AX" & j).Value < Range("AS" & j).Value Then
        Range("AX" & j) = Range("AS" & j)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop

Range("AL4:AR550").Calculate
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `j` is declared as and Integer as well. You may need to explicitly convert `j` to a string e.g. `"AX" & CStr(j)`.

Comment: Just a guess, this error is occurring because some of the compared values (inside the cells) is not a number. You need to check these cells, or if you want to ignore such cases, you can use *On Error Resume Next*

Comment: Most likely what @A.S.H mentioned. One workaround is to extract the Val() from each cell. I'll provide an answer with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the If statement to compare values only:

**`If Val(Range("AX" & j).Value) < Val(Range("AS" & j).Value) Then`**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub doStuff()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 0 To 25000
        Range("AV4:AV550").Copy
        Range("AU4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        'Check for a new high value
        For j = 4 To 551

            'check for NULL
            If IsNull(Range("AX" & j).Value) Then Range("AX" & j).Value = vbNullString
            If IsNull(Range("AS" & j).Value) Then Range("AS" & j).Value = vbNullString

            'remove special characters
            Range("AX" & j).Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(Range("AX" & j).Value))
            Range("AS" & j).Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(Range("AS" & j).Value))

            If Val(Range("AX" & j).Value) < Val(Range("AS" & j).Value) Then
                Range("AX" & j) = Range("AS" & j)
            End If
        Next
        Range("AL4:AR550").Calculate
    Next

End Sub
```

---

```
'Val() extracts any numbers it finds at the start of a string and it stops at first alpha

Public Sub testVal()
    Debug.Print "test"          '---> "test"
    Debug.Print Val("test")     '---> 0
    Debug.Print Val("123test")  '---> 123
    Debug.Print Val("test456")  '---> 0
End Sub
```

Comment: good idea @paul, but i have had some strange behavior when the cells are of type date. Seems the test of comparison always returns false (i am not using the Val trick yet) whenever one or two of ASj and AXj are dates...

Comment: And BTW, in my own test there is never a runtime error due to the type of cells. It seems VBA compares just anything to anything, only the result of comparison is undefined.

Comment: @A.S.H - good point; I'm still trying to find the most generic way to deal with unexpected data types; for comparing numbers it might work (haven't tried the dates yet)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, however, I still get a type mismatch error on that If statement.  If it helps, the data in columns AS & AX are both numeric, formatted as "Accounting" numbers.  Any other thoughts as to what might be causing the error?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On Error Resume Next did the trick.

Comment: Be careful with `On Error Resume Next`, or at least be aware that it just hides the error and moves on to the next value, and this means that you'll be missing some values you may not want to miss, However, usually these errors are usually  triggered by NULLs - best way to check for them: `IsNull(Range("AX" & j).Value)`, or hidden characters like new line \ carriage returns, or some other special character; I'll update my answer to include a check for NULLs